# Separating declaration and initialisation in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, declaration

In Java I would normally do this to separate declaration and initialisation:

```
Object obj;
obj = new Object();
```

However, this is not working in C++ when I try to seperate both:

```
unique_ptr<BTSerialPortBinding> bt; 
bt = BTSerialPortBinding::Create(dev, 1);
```

The full working statement is:

```
unique_ptr<BTSerialPortBinding>bt(BTSerialPortBinding::Create(d1.address, 1));
```

I am using this library: https://github.com/Agamnentzar/bluetooth-serial-port

```
BTSerialPortBinding::Create(address, channelID)

    Returns new instance of BTSerialPortBinding object

    address: string containint bluetooth address of the device
    channelID: ID of the serial port channel
```

I have now tried this thanks to @user1320881 's suggestion but I get the following errors when I separate the statements declaration in header file & initialisation in .cpp file

```
1>c:\users\john\ip\source\arduinodevice.h(97): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\ArduinoDevice.cpp)
1>c:\users\john\ip\source\arduinodevice.h(97): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (compiling source file ..\..\Source\ArduinoDevice.cpp)
1>c:\users\john\ip\source\arduinodevice.h(97): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\ArduinoDevice.cpp)
1>c:\users\john\ip\source\arduinodevice.cpp(45): error C2065: 'bt': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\john\ip\source\arduinodevice.cpp(45): error C2228: left of '.reset' must have class/struct/union
1>c:\users\john\ip\source\arduinodevice.cpp(45): note: type is 'unknown-type'
1>c:\users\john\ip\source\arduinodevice.cpp(54): error C2065: 'bt': undeclared identifier
```

Adding these has also cause an additional error:

```
ArduinoDevice &ArduinoDevice::operator =(const ArduinoDevice &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Relevant bit in Process.cpp file

```
dev = ArduinoDevice("/dev/tty.IP-DevB");
```

Process.h

```
#ifndef __PROCESS_H
#define __PROCESS_H

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include "ResonantLowpassFilter.h"

#include "ArduinoDevice.h"

//==============================================================================
/**
*/
class AudioProcessor  : public AudioProcessor
{
public:
    //==============================================================================
    WahwahAudioProcessor();
    ~WahwahAudioProcessor();

    void prepareToPlay (double sampleRate, int samplesPerBlock);
    void releaseResources();

    void processBlock (AudioSampleBuffer& buffer, MidiBuffer& midiMessages);

    AudioProcessorEditor* createEditor();
    int getNumParameters();
    int getNumPrograms();
    int getCurrentProgram();
    void setCurrentProgram (int index);
    const String getProgramName (int index);
    void changeProgramName (int index, const String& newName);



    float centreFrequency_, q_;
    void updateFilterArduino();

    ArduinoDevice dev; //instance to an Arduino device from which sensor data is read

};

#endif  // _PROCESS
```

ArduinoDevice.h

```
#ifndef ArduinoDevice_h
#define ArduinoDevice_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include "BTSerialPortBinding.h"

class ArduinoDevice
{
public:
    ArduinoDevice(const char *dev="");

    void connect();

    void start(void);
    void stop(void);
    void read(void);

    /**
     Disconnects from Arduino device
     **/
    ~ArduinoDevice();

private:
    const char *device; //port address of the device (e.g. "/dev/tty.FireFly-E552-SPP")

    std::unique_ptr<BTSerialPortBinding> bt; //bt serial port 

    void close(void);

};

#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use member `reset` to assign a new pointer to the unique_ptr and delete the previously managed pointer, if any.

```
bt.reset(BTSerialPortBinding::Create(dev, 1));
```

Comment: When I declare unique_ptr<BTSerialPortBinding> bt; in my header file and your statement in the .cpp file i get the following errors:  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\ArduinoDevice.cpp)

Comment: `unique_ptr<BTSerialPortBinding> bt;` in the header file ? Is it inside a class ? Because you should not instantiate objects in a header. Also this implies you're `using namespace std` in the header, never use namespaces in headers. Use the full scope `std::unique_ptr<BTSerialPortBinding>`

Comment: I put 'unique_ptr<BTSerialPortBinding> bt' in the header file to declare it and 'bt.reset(BTSerialPortBinding::Create(dev, 1));' to initiate in the .cpp file. Should i put std::unique_ptr<BTSerialPortBinding> in the header file. I have edited my answer to include the full errors.

Comment: Unless it is INSIDE another class you should not instantiate objects in a header. So `class MyClass { std::unique_ptr<BTSerialPortBinding> bt; }; ` is fine, but a raw `std::unique_ptr<BTSerialPortBinding> bt; ` is not - if this is what you want you should instantiate it in the C file and use `extern` in the header.

Comment: the header contains a class yes, but once I do this operation I suddenly get an error saying: `ArduinoDevice &ArduinoDevice::operator =(const ArduinoDevice &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`: coming from `dev = ArduinoDevice("/dev/tty.IP-DevB");` in another `Process.cpp` dev is declared in the `Process.h` and is an instance of ArduinoDevice

Comment: Can you perhaps post the contents of the header file and the relevant section of your cpp file ?

Comment: You forgot to include header memory in ArduinoDevice.h for std::unique_ptr: `#include <memory>`

Comment: Added it in but unfortunately still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Object *obj;
obj = new Object();
```

because the `new Object();` return an  address so  you have to store it in  a pointer.